# couchDB: Naive Questions

Tags: couchdb

**Download / Backup / Reload**

Is there any equivalent to MySQL UNLOAD ?

**Database Location**

Are the database files, viewable with a browser or are they stored above the public_html root ?

**Javascript**

If the data can be accessed with javascript.  How are passwords hidden from the client ?

**Hosting**

Do any websites offer couchDB as a standard offering like MySQL ?

**phpMyAdmin**

Is there an equivalent for couchDB ?

Thanks

mcl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any equivalent to MySQL UNLOAD ?

There is no native export functionality, but you can replicate between two databases very easily via futon (couchdb's built-in admin interface).

If you really want a backup as a file, you can "export" all data via the _all_docs api (see http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API), but _all_docs doesn't include attachments - you have to get them separately.

> Are the database files, viewable with a browser or are they stored above the public_html root ?

The database files are not accessible fron the outside. Why would you want to open them? There is one file per database, and it can quickly grow to several gigabytes. You wouldn't want to open those files, trust me ;-)

As they are append-only, you can safely backup those, though...

> If the data can be accessed with javascript. How are passwords hidden from the client ?

One has nothing to do with the other. Javascript as one possible language for queries is executed on the server, and it wouldn't make any difference if it were PHP or Java. You don't need JavaScript at all on the client - you can serve your data in plain HTML directly from CouchDB.

How passwords are hidden depends on what you mean: passwords have to be provided by the client, and the user passwords are stored as a hash in the _users database (but you can use other authentication mechanisms, too).

> Do any websites offer couchDB as a standard offering like MySQL ?

You can try CouchDB on http://www.iriscouch.com - they offer free CouchDB hosting.

> phpMyAdmin - Is there an equivalent for couchDB ?

Yes - it's the built in futon interface. You can reach it via .../_utils from your browser. But the interface is quite different - Couch is No SQL database... ;-)

Hope I could help!

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am much more enlightened, except for the javascript bit.  I obviously need to find out how to access the data, as I thought it was through jquery functions. mcl

Comment: You mentioned that backups do not include attachments and they have to be backed up separately.

Comment: Sorry messed up last comment and then timed out the edit.  You mentioned that backups do not include attachments and they have to be backed up separately.  Where do you find these attachments ?Thanks to your advice, I successfully added a couple of records in iriscouch, including an attachment ( a jpeg file).  How would I display that attachment and would it be possible to get its description from the IPTC field in the jpeg ?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear about this: all attachments are stored with your document. If you have a document with an _id "test", you would get the raw document via mycouch.com/mydatabase/test. An attachment called thumb.jpg can be retrieved via mycouch.com/mydatabase/test/thumb.jpg. But you cannot download all attachments for all documents at once (which is what you would need for a backup).